# What is the reasoning behind x64 having such a different performance result from x86?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, compilation, internal

I was answering [a question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165407/optimizing-special-cases-of-modulo/165821#165821) and I discovered an interesting difference in performance (like, a *lot*) between x64 and x86.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<ModVsOptimization>();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    static public ulong Mersenne5(ulong dividend)
    {
        dividend = (dividend >> 32) + (dividend & 0xFFFFFFFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 16) + (dividend & 0xFFFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 8) + (dividend & 0xFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
        if (dividend > 14) { dividend = dividend - 15; } // mod 15
        if (dividend > 10) { dividend = dividend - 10; }
        if (dividend > 4) { dividend = dividend - 5; }
        return dividend;
    }
}

public class ModVsOptimization
{
    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public ulong RawModulo_5()
    {
        ulong r = 0;
        for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            r += i % 5;
        }
        return r;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ulong OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5()
    {
        ulong r = 0;
        for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            r += Program.Mersenne5(i);
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

### x86:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.8, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 2 (10.0.15063)
Processor=Intel Core i7-5930K CPU 3.50GHz (Broadwell), ProcessorCount=12
Frequency=3415991 Hz, Resolution=292.7408 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2098.0
  DefaultJob : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2098.0


                      Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Scaled |
---------------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|-------:|
                 RawModulo_5 | 4.601 us | 0.0121 us | 0.0107 us |   1.00 |
 OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5 | 7.990 us | 0.0060 us | 0.0053 us |   1.74 |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  ModVsOptimization.RawModulo_5: Default                 -> 1 outlier  was  removed
  ModVsOptimization.OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5: Default -> 1 outlier  was  removed

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Scaled : Mean(CurrentBenchmark) / Mean(BaselineBenchmark)
  1 us   : 1 Microsecond (0.000001 sec)

// ***** BenchmarkRunner: End *****
```

### x64:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.8, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 2 (10.0.15063)
Processor=Intel Core i7-5930K CPU 3.50GHz (Broadwell), ProcessorCount=12
Frequency=3415991 Hz, Resolution=292.7408 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2098.0
  DefaultJob : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2098.0


                      Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Scaled |
---------------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|-------:|
                 RawModulo_5 | 8.323 us | 0.0042 us | 0.0039 us |   1.00 |
 OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5 | 2.597 us | 0.0956 us | 0.0982 us |   0.31 |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  ModVsOptimization.OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5: Default -> 2 outliers were removed

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Scaled : Mean(CurrentBenchmark) / Mean(BaselineBenchmark)
  1 us   : 1 Microsecond (0.000001 sec)

// ***** BenchmarkRunner: End *****
```

Now here's the part that get's interesting, which doesn't necessarily surprise me (due to the manner in which I especially that the C# compiler works), both the x86 and x64 assemblies have the same IL for the `RawModulo_5` method:

```
.method public hidebysig instance uint64 
        RawModulo_5() cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [BenchmarkDotNet.Core]BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes.BenchmarkAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 01 00 54 02 08 42 61 73 65 6C 69 6E 65 01 ) // ....T..Baseline.
  // Code size       31 (0x1f)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] uint64 r,
           [1] uint64 i)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0001:  conv.i8
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0004:  conv.i8
  IL_0005:  stloc.1
  IL_0006:  br.s       IL_0014
  IL_0008:  ldloc.0
  IL_0009:  ldloc.1
  IL_000a:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_000b:  conv.i8
  IL_000c:  rem.un
  IL_000d:  add
  IL_000e:  stloc.0
  IL_000f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0011:  conv.i8
  IL_0012:  add
  IL_0013:  stloc.1
  IL_0014:  ldloc.1
  IL_0015:  ldc.i4     0x3e8
  IL_001a:  conv.i8
  IL_001b:  blt.un.s   IL_0008
  IL_001d:  ldloc.0
  IL_001e:  ret
} // end of method ModVsOptimization::RawModulo_5
```

Now I'm not sure where to look next, but I suspect the issue is somewhere in the JITter, though I tested on RyuJIT and LegacyJIT, both had the same general result with the x64 architecture (though LegacyJIT was *slightly* slower overall). These are run in Release mode *outside* of Visual Studio, so I'm assuming there's no attached debugging session to be causing it.

So I'm curious, what is causing this? I have no idea how to investigate further, but if anyone has any ideas on further investigation steps, feel free to comment and I'll gladly try to perform them.

Comment: It's been too long since I've done dotnet stuff - is there a a way to get the optimized JIT disassembly for `RawModulo_5` for each target?  How many times does the benchmark framework run the method under test?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have *absolutely* no idea how to get the JIT output / disassembly, and it's running each method 14-16 times. I'll look into getting the JIT disassembly, to see if that lends a clue.

Comment: Does it have something to do with memory? What does memory usage look like when you run under x86 and x64?

Comment: @garethb In theory that's possible, after running to completion the 64-bit version consumes 34.1MB of RAM, and the 32-bit version consumes 21.0MB of RAM.

Comment: Because x86 is 32 bit (with some magic to run on 64 bit systems) and x64 is true 64 bit.  x86 is basically a 32 bit app that can communicate to 64 bit architecture but doesn't have any of the 64 bit benefits.

Comment: I'm doing an analysis for you of the actual assembly code. I have a few guesses but I'm curious to see how it plays out. Will post an answer in a bit.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII That doesn't really make sense though, because if that were the case one would expect that both the methods would be slower on one or the other, but here we get a *substantial* difference in speed and it flip/flops. The result is inconsistent, which tells me that something else is up.

Comment: @EBrown  It's because of the difference in calculations.  You can get a closer number in 64bit but it will carry a lot further ie with decimals etc.

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to do an analysis of the generated assembly code to see what was going on. I grabbed your example code and ran it in Release mode. This is using Visual Studio 2015 with .NET Framework 4.5.2. CPU is an Intel Ivy Bridge i5-3570K, in case the JIT makes very specific optimizations. I ran the same test but without your benchmarking suite, just using a simple `Stopwatch` and dividing the time in ticks by the iteration count. Here is what I observed:

```
RawModulo_5, x86:                 13721978 ticks, 13.721978 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5, x86: 24641039 ticks, 24.641039 ticks per iteration

RawModulo_5, x64:                 23275799 ticks, 23.275799 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5, x64: 13389012 ticks, 13.389012 ticks per iteration
```

This is somewhat different from your measurements - the performance of each method more or less flips depending on x86 versus x64. Your measurements have much more stark differences, particularly between each implementation and its other-arch counterpart. `RawModulo_5` is a little less than twice as slow in x64, while `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5` is 3.7x faster in x64!

**Also, I hope you're not expecting the outputs of `RawModulo_5` and `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5` to be equal, because they are not! The correct `Mersenne5` implementation is below:**

```
static public ulong Mersenne5(ulong dividend)
{
    dividend = (dividend >> 32) + (dividend & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    dividend = (dividend >> 16) + (dividend & 0xFFFF);
    dividend = (dividend >> 8) + (dividend & 0xFF);
    dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
    // there was an extra shift by 4 here
    if (dividend > 14) { dividend = dividend - 15; } // mod 15
    // the 9 used to be a 10
    if (dividend > 9) { dividend = dividend - 10; }
    if (dividend > 4) { dividend = dividend - 5; }
    return dividend;
}
```

To gather the instructions on my system, I added a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` within each method, just before the loops and the body of `Mersenne5`, so that I'd have a definite break point to grab the generated assembly. By the way, you can grab generated assembly code from the Visual Studio UI - if you're at a breakpoint you can right click the code editor window and select "Go To Disassembly" from the context menu. I've annotated the assembly to explain what it's doing. Sorry for the crazy syntax highlighting.

#### x86, RawModulo_5 method

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
00242DA2  in          al,dx  
00242DA3  push        edi  
00242DA4  push        ebx  
00242DA5  sub         esp,10h  
00242DA8  call        6D4C0178  
            ulong r = 0;
00242DAD  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],0  ; setting the low and high dwords of 'r'
00242DB4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],0  
            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
; set the high dword of 'i' to 0
00242DBB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],0
; clear the low dword of 'i' to 0 - the compiler is using 'edi' as the loop iteration var
00242DC2  xor         edi,edi  
            {
                r += i % 5;
00242DC4  mov         eax,edi  
00242DC6  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
; edx:eax together are the high and low dwords of 'i', respectively

; this is a short circuit trick so it can avoid working with the high
; dword - you can see it jumps halfway in to the div/mod operation below
00242DC9  mov         ecx,5  
00242DCE  cmp         edx,ecx  
00242DD0  jb          00242DDC  
; 64 bit div/mod operation
00242DD2  mov         ebx,eax  
00242DD4  mov         eax,edx  
00242DD6  xor         edx,edx  
00242DD8  div         eax,ecx  
00242DDA  mov         eax,ebx  
00242DDC  div         eax,ecx  
00242DDE  mov         eax,edx  
00242DE0  xor         edx,edx
; load the current low and high dwords from 'r', then add into
; edx:eax as a pair forming a qword
00242DE2  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
00242DE5  adc         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
; store the result back in 'r'
00242DE8  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
00242DEB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx  
            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
; load the loop variable low and high dwords into edx:eax
00242DEE  mov         eax,edi  
00242DF0  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
; increment eax (the low dword) and propagate any carries to
; edx (the high dword)
00242DF3  add         eax,1  
00242DF6  adc         edx,0  
; store the low and high dwords back to the high word of 'i' and
; the loop iteration counter, 'edi'
00242DF9  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],edx  
00242DFC  mov         edi,eax
; test the high dword  
00242DFE  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-14h],0  
00242E02  ja          00242E0E  
00242E04  jb          00242DC4  
; (int) i < 1000
00242E06  cmp         edi,3E8h  
00242E0C  jb          00242DC4  
            }
            return r;
; retrieve the current value of 'r' from memory, return value is
; in edx:eax since the return value is 64 bits
00242E0E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
00242E11  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
00242E14  lea         esp,[ebp-8]  
00242E17  pop         ebx  
00242E18  pop         edi  
00242E19  pop         ebp  
00242E1A  ret
```

#### x86, OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
00242E33  push        edi  
00242E34  push        esi  
00242E35  push        ebx  
00242E36  sub         esp,8  
00242E39  call        6D4C0178  
            ulong r = 0;
; same as above, initialize 'r' to zero using low and high dwords
00242E3E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],0  
; this time we're using edi:esi as the loop counter, rather than
; edi and a memory location. probably less register pressure in this
; function, for reasons we'll see...
00242E45  xor         ebx,ebx  
            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
; initialize 'i' to 0, esi is the loop counter low dword, edi is the high dword
00242E47  xor         esi,esi  
00242E49  xor         edi,edi  
; push 'i' to the stack, high word then low word
00242E4B  push        edi  
00242E4C  push        esi  
; call Mersenne5 - it got put in the data section since it's static
00242E4D  call        dword ptr ds:[3D7830h]  
; return value comes back as edx:eax, where edx is the high dword
; ebx is the existing low dword of 'r', so it's accumulated into eax
00242E53  add         eax,ebx  
; the high dword of 'r' is at ebp-10, that gets accumulated to edx with
; the carry result of the last add since it's 64 bits wide
00242E55  adc         edx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]
; store edx:ebx back to 'r'  
00242E58  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],edx  
00242E5B  mov         ebx,eax  
; increment the loop counter and carry to edi as well, 64 bit add
00242E5D  add         esi,1  
00242E60  adc         edi,0  
; make sure edi == 0 since it's the high dword
00242E63  test        edi,edi  
00242E65  ja          00242E71  
00242E67  jb          00242E4B  
; (int) i < 1000
00242E69  cmp         esi,3E8h  
00242E6F  jb          00242E4B  
            }
            return r;
; move 'r' to edx:eax to return them
00242E71  mov         eax,ebx  
00242E73  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
00242E76  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
00242E79  pop         ebx  
00242E7A  pop         esi  
00242E7B  pop         edi  
00242E7C  pop         ebp  
00242E7D  ret
```

#### x86, Mersenne5() method

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
00342E92  in          al,dx  
00342E93  push        edi  
00342E94  push        esi  
; esi is the low dword, edi is the high dword of the 64 bit argument
00342E95  mov         esi,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
00342E98  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
00342E9B  call        6D4C0178  
            dividend = (dividend >> 32) + (dividend & 0xFFFFFFFF);
; this is a LOT of instructions for each step, but at least it's all registers.

; copy edi:esi to edx:eax
00342EA0  mov         eax,esi  
00342EA2  mov         edx,edi
; clobber eax with edx, so now both are the high word. this is a
; shorthand for a 32 bit shift right of a 64 bit number.  
00342EA4  mov         eax,edx
; clear the high word now that we've moved the high word to the low word  
00342EA6  xor         edx,edx
; clear the high word of the original 'dividend', same as masking the low 32 bits  
00342EA8  xor         edi,edi  
; (dividend >> 32) + (dividend & 0xFFFFFFFF)
; it's a 64 bit add, so it's the usual add/adc
00342EAA  add         eax,esi  
00342EAC  adc         edx,edi
; 'dividend' now equals the temporary "variable" that held the addition result  
00342EAE  mov         esi,eax  
00342EB0  mov         edi,edx  
            dividend = (dividend >> 16) + (dividend & 0xFFFF);
; same idea as above, but with an actual shift and mask since it's not 32 bits wide
00342EB2  mov         eax,esi  
00342EB4  mov         edx,edi  
00342EB6  shrd        eax,edx,10h  
00342EBA  shr         edx,10h  
00342EBD  and         esi,0FFFFh  
00342EC3  xor         edi,edi  
00342EC5  add         eax,esi  
00342EC7  adc         edx,edi  
00342EC9  mov         esi,eax  
00342ECB  mov         edi,edx  
            dividend = (dividend >> 8) + (dividend & 0xFF);
; same idea, keep going down...
00342ECD  mov         eax,esi  
00342ECF  mov         edx,edi  
00342ED1  shrd        eax,edx,8  
00342ED5  shr         edx,8  
00342ED8  and         esi,0FFh  
00342EDE  xor         edi,edi  
00342EE0  add         eax,esi  
00342EE2  adc         edx,edi  
00342EE4  mov         esi,eax  
00342EE6  mov         edi,edx  
            dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
00342EE8  mov         eax,esi  
00342EEA  mov         edx,edi  
00342EEC  shrd        eax,edx,4  
00342EF0  shr         edx,4  
00342EF3  and         esi,0Fh  
00342EF6  xor         edi,edi  
00342EF8  add         eax,esi  
00342EFA  adc         edx,edi  
00342EFC  mov         esi,eax  
00342EFE  mov         edi,edx  
            dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
00342F00  mov         eax,esi  
00342F02  mov         edx,edi  
00342F04  shrd        eax,edx,4  
00342F08  shr         edx,4  
00342F0B  and         esi,0Fh  
00342F0E  xor         edi,edi  
00342F10  add         eax,esi  
00342F12  adc         edx,edi  
00342F14  mov         esi,eax  
00342F16  mov         edi,edx  
            if (dividend > 14) { dividend = dividend - 15; } // mod 15
; conditional subtraction
00342F18  test        edi,edi  
00342F1A  ja          00342F23  
00342F1C  jb          00342F29  
; 'dividend' > 14
00342F1E  cmp         esi,0Eh  
00342F21  jbe         00342F29  
; 'dividend' = 'dividend' - 15
00342F23  sub         esi,0Fh 
; subtraction borrow from high word 
00342F26  sbb         edi,0  
            if (dividend > 10) { dividend = dividend - 10; }
; same gist for the next two
00342F29  test        edi,edi  
00342F2B  ja          00342F34  
00342F2D  jb          00342F3A  
00342F2F  cmp         esi,0Ah  
00342F32  jbe         00342F3A  
00342F34  sub         esi,0Ah  
00342F37  sbb         edi,0  
            if (dividend > 4) { dividend = dividend - 5; }
00342F3A  test        edi,edi  
00342F3C  ja          00342F45  
00342F3E  jb          00342F4B  
00342F40  cmp         esi,4  
00342F43  jbe         00342F4B  
00342F45  sub         esi,5  
00342F48  sbb         edi,0  
            return dividend;
; move edi:esi into edx:eax for return
00342F4B  mov         eax,esi  
00342F4D  mov         edx,edi  
00342F4F  pop         esi  
00342F50  pop         edi  
00342F51  pop         ebp  
00342F52  ret         8
```

The first big thing I notice is that Mersenne5 is not actually getting inlined, even though it's listed tagged as `AggressiveInlining`. I'm guessing this is because inlining the function inside `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5` would cause horrific register spilling, and the large amount of memory reads and writes would completely destroy the point of inlining the method, so the compiler elected (quite wisely!) not to do so.

Second, Mersenne5 is getting `call`'d 1000 times by `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5`, so there's 1000 pieces of extra call/ret overhead being experienced, including the necessary pushes and pops to save register states across the call boundary. `RawModulo_5` doesn't make any calls outside, and even the 64 bit division is optimized a bit so it skips the high `dword` where it can.

#### x64, RawModulo_5 method

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
000007FE98C93CF0  sub         rsp,28h  
000007FE98C93CF4  call        000007FEF7B079C0  
            ulong r = 0;
; the compiler knows the high dword of rcx is already 0, so it just
; zeros the low dword. this is 'r'
000007FE98C93CF9  xor         ecx,ecx  
            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
; same here, this is 'i'
000007FE98C93CFB  xor         r8d,r8d  
            {
                r += i % 5;
; load 5 as a dword to the low dword of r9
000007FE98C93CFE  mov         r9d,5  
; copy the loop counter to rax for the div below
000007FE98C93D04  mov         rax,r8  
; clear the lower dword of rdx, upper dword is clear already
000007FE98C93D07  xor         edx,edx  
; 64 bit div/mod in one instruction! but it's slow!
000007FE98C93D09  div         rax,r9  
; rax = quotient, rdx = remainder
; throw away the quotient since we're just doing mod, and accumulate the
; modulus into 'r'
000007FE98C93D0C  add         rcx,rdx  
            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
; 64 bit increment to the loop counter
000007FE98C93D0F  inc         r8  
; i < 1000
000007FE98C93D12  cmp         r8,3E8h  
000007FE98C93D19  jb          000007FE98C93CFE  
            }
            return r;
; return 'r' in rax, since we can directly return a 64 bit var in one register now
000007FE98C93D1B  mov         rax,rcx  
000007FE98C93D1E  add         rsp,28h  
000007FE98C93D22  ret
```

#### x64, OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
000007FE98C94040  push        rdi  
000007FE98C94041  push        rsi  
000007FE98C94042  sub         rsp,28h  
000007FE98C94046  call        000007FEF7B079C0  
            ulong r = 0;
; same general loop setup as above
000007FE98C9404B  xor         esi,esi  
            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
; 'edi' is the loop counter
000007FE98C9404D  xor         edi,edi  
; put rdi in rcx, which is the x64 register used for the first argument
; in a call
000007FE98C9404F  mov         rcx,rdi  
; call Mersenne5 - still no actual inlining!
000007FE98C94052  call        000007FE98C90F40  
; accumulate 'r' with the return value of Mersenne5
000007FE98C94057  add         rax,rsi  
; store back to 'r' - I don't know why in the world the compiler did this
; seems like add rsi, rax would be better, but maybe there's a pipelining
; issue I'm not seeing.
000007FE98C9405A  mov         rsi,rax  
; increment loop counter
000007FE98C9405D  inc         rdi  
; i < 1000
000007FE98C94060  cmp         rdi,3E8h  
000007FE98C94067  jb          000007FE98C9404F  
            }
            return r;
; put return value in rax like before
000007FE98C94069  mov         rax,rsi  
000007FE98C9406C  add         rsp,28h  
000007FE98C94070  pop         rsi  
000007FE98C94071  pop         rdi  
000007FE98C94072  ret
```

#### x64, Mersenne5 method

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
000007FE98C94580  push        rsi  
000007FE98C94581  sub         rsp,20h  
000007FE98C94585  mov         rsi,rcx  
000007FE98C94588  call        000007FEF7B079C0  
            dividend = (dividend >> 32) + (dividend & 0xFFFFFFFF);
; pretty similar to before actually, except this time we do a real
; shift and mask for the 32 bit part
000007FE98C9458D  mov         rax,rsi  
; 'dividend' >> 32
000007FE98C94590  shr         rax,20h  
; hilariously, we have to load the mask into edx first. this is because
; there is no AND r/64, imm64 in x64
000007FE98C94594  mov         edx,0FFFFFFFFh  
000007FE98C94599  and         rsi,rdx  
; add the shift and the masked versions together
000007FE98C9459C  add         rax,rsi  
000007FE98C9459F  mov         rsi,rax  
            dividend = (dividend >> 16) + (dividend & 0xFFFF);
; same logic continues down
000007FE98C945A2  mov         rax,rsi  
000007FE98C945A5  shr         rax,10h  
000007FE98C945A9  mov         rdx,rsi  
000007FE98C945AC  and         rdx,0FFFFh  
000007FE98C945B3  add         rax,rdx  

; note the redundant moves that happen every time, rax into rsi, rsi
; into rax. so there's still not ideal x64 being generated.
000007FE98C945B6  mov         rsi,rax  
            dividend = (dividend >> 8) + (dividend & 0xFF);
000007FE98C945B9  mov         rax,rsi  
000007FE98C945BC  shr         rax,8  
000007FE98C945C0  mov         rdx,rsi  
000007FE98C945C3  and         rdx,0FFh  
000007FE98C945CA  add         rax,rdx  
000007FE98C945CD  mov         rsi,rax  
            dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
000007FE98C945D0  mov         rax,rsi  
000007FE98C945D3  shr         rax,4  
000007FE98C945D7  mov         rdx,rsi  
000007FE98C945DA  and         rdx,0Fh  
000007FE98C945DE  add         rax,rdx  
000007FE98C945E1  mov         rsi,rax  
            dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
000007FE98C945E4  mov         rax,rsi  
000007FE98C945E7  shr         rax,4  
000007FE98C945EB  mov         rdx,rsi  
000007FE98C945EE  and         rdx,0Fh  
000007FE98C945F2  add         rax,rdx  
000007FE98C945F5  mov         rsi,rax  
            if (dividend > 14) { dividend = dividend - 15; } // mod 15
; notice the difference in jumping logic - the pairs of jumps are now singles
000007FE98C945F8  cmp         rsi,0Eh  
000007FE98C945FC  jbe         000007FE98C94602 
; using a single 64 bit add instead of a subtract, the immediate constant
; is the 2's complement of 15. this is okay because there's no borrowing
; to do since we can do the entire sub in one operation to one register. 
000007FE98C945FE  add         rsi,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF1h  
            if (dividend > 10) { dividend = dividend - 10; }
000007FE98C94602  cmp         rsi,0Ah  
000007FE98C94606  jbe         000007FE98C9460C  
000007FE98C94608  add         rsi,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF6h  
            if (dividend > 4) { dividend = dividend - 5; }
000007FE98C9460C  cmp         rsi,4  
000007FE98C94610  jbe         000007FE98C94616  
000007FE98C94612  add         rsi,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBh  
            return dividend;
000007FE98C94616  mov         rax,rsi  
000007FE98C94619  add         rsp,20h  
000007FE98C9461D  pop         rsi  
000007FE98C9461E  ret
```

---

All the x64 methods look better than their x86 counterparts, but there is still the question of why `RawModulo_5` is twice as slow in x64 compared to x86, and especially why `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5` is almost four times faster under x64 than x86. To get a full explanation I think we'd need someone like Peter Cordes - he's far more knowledgeable than I am with regard to instruction timings and pipelining. Here are my intuitions as to where the advantages and disadvantages are coming from.

1. **[x64 con]** `div` in x86 versus x64 as it concerns `RawModulo_5`

   According to the instruction tables provided by Agner Fog [here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), on Broadwell a 32 bit `div` takes 10 micro-ops and has a latency of 22 to 29 clocks, while 64 bit `div` takes 36 micro-ops and has a latency of 32 to 95 clocks.

   The compiler also made an optimization in x86 `RawModulo_5` that bypasses the high dword `div` in every case, since the loop stays below `int.MaxValue`, so in reality it's just doing a single 32 bit `div` on each iteration. Thus, the 64 bit `div` latency is between 1.45 and 3.27 times higher than the 32 bit `div` latency. Both versions have total dependencies on the results of the `div`, so the x64 code is paying a much larger performance penalty because of the higher latency. I would venture that the pair of add/adc instructions for 64 bit adds in x86 `RawModulo_5` are a tiny penalty versus the huge performance disadvantage of the 64 bit wide `div`.
2. **[x64 pro]** Reduced call overhead in x64 `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5`

   This is probably not a huge difference in terms of performance, but it's worth mentioning. Because `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5` is calling `Mersenne5` 1000 times in both versions, the 64 bit version is paying far less a penalty in terms of the standard x86 versus x64 calling convention. Consider that the x86 version has to push two registers to the stack to pass a 64 bit variable, then `Mersenne5` has to preserve `esi` and `edi`, then pull the high and low dwords out of the stack for `edx` and `eax` respectively. At the end, `Mersenne5` has to restore `esi` and `edi`. In the x64 version, the value of `i` is passed in `ecx` directly, so no memory access is involved at all. The x64 `Mersenne5` only saves and restores `rsi`, the other registers are clobbered.
3. **[x64 pro]** Many fewer instructions in x64 `Mersenne5`

   `Mersenne5` is more efficient in x64 as it can perform all the operations on the 64 bit `dividend` in single instructions, versus requiring pairs of instructions in x86 for the `mov` and `add/adc` operations. I have a hunch that the dependency chains are better in x64 as well, but I am not knowledgeable enough to speak on that subject.
4. **[x64 pro]** Better jump behavior in x64 `Mersenne5`

   The three conditional subtractions that `Mersenne5` does at the end are implemented much better under x64 than x86. On x86, each one has two comparisons and three possible conditional jumps that can be taken. On x64, there is only one comparison and one conditional jump, which is undoubtedly more efficient.

---

With those points in mind, it makes some sense for Ivy Bridge we'd see the performance of each flip-flop from x86 to x64. It's likely that the 64 bit division latency penalty (which is a little worse on Ivy Bridge than Broadwell, but not much) is hurting `RawModulo_5` quite a bit, and the near halving of instructions in `Mersenne5` is speeding up `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5` at the same time.

What doesn't make sense is the results on Broadwell - I'm still a little surprised how much faster the x64 `OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5` is, even compared to the x86 `RawModulo_5`. I imagine the answer would be micro-op fusion and pipelining for the `Mersenne5` method is considerably better on x64, or perhaps the JIT on your architecture is using Broadwell-specific knowledge to output very different instructions.

I'm sorry I can't give a more conclusive answer, but I hope the analysis above is enlightening as to why there's a difference between the two methods and the two architectures.

By the way, if you want to see what a truly inlined version can do, here you go:

```
RawModulo_5, x86:                  13722506 ticks, 13.722506 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5, x86:  23640994 ticks, 23.640994 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_TrueInlined, x86:  21488012 ticks, 21.488012 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_TrueInlined2, x86: 21645697 ticks, 21.645697 ticks per iteration

RawModulo_5, x64:                 22175326 ticks, 22.175326 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_ViaMethod_5, x64: 12822574 ticks, 12.822574 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_TrueInlined, x64:  7612328 ticks,  7.612328 ticks per iteration
OptimizedModulo_TrueInlined2, x64: 7591190 ticks,  7.59119 ticks per iteration
```

And the code:

```
public ulong OptimizedModulo_TrueInlined()
{
    ulong r = 0;
    ulong dividend = 0;

    for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        dividend = i;
        dividend = (dividend >> 32) + (dividend & 0xFFFFFFFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 16) + (dividend & 0xFFFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 8) + (dividend & 0xFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
        if (dividend > 14) { dividend = dividend - 15; } // mod 15
        if (dividend > 10) { dividend = dividend - 10; }
        if (dividend > 4) { dividend = dividend - 5; }
        r += dividend;
    }
    return r;
}

public ulong OptimizedModulo_TrueInlined2()
{
    ulong r = 0;
    ulong dividend = 0;

    for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        dividend = (i >> 32) + (i & 0xFFFFFFFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 16) + (dividend & 0xFFFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 8) + (dividend & 0xFF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
        dividend = (dividend >> 4) + (dividend & 0xF);
        if (dividend > 14) { dividend = dividend - 15; } // mod 15
        if (dividend > 10) { dividend = dividend - 10; }
        if (dividend > 4) { dividend = dividend - 5; }
        r += dividend;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: This is phenomenal. Using the trick you mentioned, I verified that my disassembly for `RawModulo_5` is the same as yours on x86 and x64, so it must be the 64-bit `DIV` instruction creating all this havoc. I never thought I would ever notice a processor internal issue like this. I wonder if there's place for a compiler-optimization from the ladies and gentlemen at Microsoft on this one.

Comment: @EBrown the answer doesn't mention this, but you *need* to make sure that the setting in Tools->Options->Debugging->General->Suppress JIT optimizations on module load is unchecked, if you want to see the optimized code in release mode under the debugger.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Correct, although I believe in Visual Studio 2015 (at least) that is unchecked by default.

Comment: @EBrown The trouble is that we're only computing modulus with a fixed divisor of 5. For general purpose uses, the processor's built in `div` works quite well. When you start doing general purpose modulus using a method table of implementations like `Mersenne5`, as was the case in the code review post you linked, things start going south in terms of performance. Eventually you might have so many methods that instruction cache misses become a latency issue. However, for cases like this where the divisor is const, I agree the compiler could perhaps output a special version in pure assembly.

Comment: One note, the "extra" shift is not extra. Without it 2147483645, for example, will not give the correct result.

Comment: @ozeanix this code was written to explore a very specific use case where the divisor is determined at runtime and the Func with a modulo implementation is used millions to maybe billions of times on different dividends. Then the divisor likely changes and a new Func is used again millions of times etc. It's also required to be built for x64.

Comment: Makes sense @quentin-starin, that's why I said in a general case the `div` instruction is fine, especially if the divisor is not known ahead of time. It was very surprising to me that even with the `call` instruction and all of the shifts, ands, and moves that the `Mersenne5` method was so much faster than the built in `div`, but I can see now the 64 bit wide `div` performance is absolutely terrible on x64, so it makes perfect sense to exploit this special case and have code that is nearly 4x faster.

Comment: @ozeanix I very much appreciate your analysis. Micro/nano benchamarking is not something I've done much at all and my assembly is awfully rusty (mostly familiar with 8 bit microcontrollers from 20 years ago). You've given me much to consider and it is quite interesting to see why the performance differs (and how the JIT'd assembly might still be subpar). Thank you for your time.

Comment: "The compiler also made an optimization in x86 RawModulo_5 that bypasses the high dword div in every case, since the loop stays below int.MaxValue" This made me curious. Without that optimization the speed advantage of % on x86 (Skylake) evaporates and Mersenne executes faster than % even when not called through an additional Func<> (not much faster, but that optimization makes a fair difference): https://gist.github.com/qstarin/136ae1a22499705c38e0cc5f001df371

Comment: @quentin-starin Yep, it's almost entirely because of the horrific 64 bit wide `div` performance. I have no idea about the internal microcode or hardware it uses to compute div, but it's certainly within reason that doubling the bit width vastly increases the implementation complexity. One thing you might also consider is using SIMD to compute fixed divisor modulus if you're doing a huge number of them, although I'm rusty on whether there's a 256 bit 4-way 64 bit integer divide or modulo in AVX2.

Answer (score 14):

```
  r += i % 5;
```

This is the bottleneck statement in the code snippet, as explained well by @ozeanix.  I'll annotate his extensive answer.

Division is one of the hard operations a processor has to perform, there is no known digital circuit that can execute division in a single cycle.  It has to be implemented with an iterative approach, not fundamentally different from the way you learned to do it in elementary school.  Execution time is proportional to the number of bits, a 64-bit division can be expected to be twice as slow as a 32-bit division.

The x86 jitter, having to generate the cumbersome code to do the math with only 32-bit registers, took a shortcut for the case where the upper 32-bits of the `ulong` are 0.  That turned out well in this specific case, 999 and 5 are small enough.  Do note how much faster the 64-bit code is on the Mersenne5() method, being able to use a single register to store intermediate values and a single shift instruction to move 64-bits at a time gives it a big leg up.

The x64 jitter cannot use the same trick the x86 jitter uses, not without making the code slower, the upper 32-bits of a 64-bit register are not directly addressable.  That does not mean that you are stuck with the slower perf, with sufficient trust any pig can be made to fly.  I'll show a coding trick that I reverse-engineered from a C compiler optimizer.  It works in this specific case because you repeatedly use the same divisor.  Just to illustrate the trick, this is the machine code that such a compiler generates in its inner loop with loop unrolling and instruction mixing removed:

```
00007FF603121006  mov         rax,0CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDh    ; magic!
00007FF603121010  mul         rax,r9                    ; magic * i
00007FF603121013  shr         rdx,2                     ; rdx = (magic * i) / 4 / 2^64 
00007FF603121017  lea         rcx,[rdx+rdx*4]           ; 5 * rdx
00007FF60312101B  mov         rdx,r9                    ; i
00007FF60312101E  sub         rdx,rcx                   ; i - 5 * ((magic * i) / 4 / 2^64)
00007FF603121024  add         r8,rdx                    ; r += i % 5
```

This is, cough, hard to make sense of.  Key point is that the code does not use the DIV instruction at all, but can do it with SHR, that makes it very fast.  SHR is the exact equivalent of the `>>` operator in C#, right-shifting is equivalent to dividing by powers of 2.

The big trick is to transform a division by 5 into a division by a power of 2.  This is not in general possible, but it can be approximated.  It takes some rewriting tricks to see that.  It starts with the identity that transforms modulo into division:

```
A % B == A - B * (A / B)
```

Transform the division by multiplying the left and right side by N/B where N is a convenient power of 2:

```
A % B == A - B * ((A * N / B) / N)
```

Since N / B is known up front it can be hoisted out of the loop.  I should emphasize that this identity is only valid for floating point division.  We want to use integer division instead.  Thus:

```
A % B ~= A - B * (A * K / N)   where K ~= N / B
```

The approximation for K is the more accurate the larger a value we pick for N.  The C compiler code uses a *very* large value for N, 4 * 2^64, taking advantage of a 64-bit multiplication producing a 128-bit result.  Something we cannot do in C#, we have to pick a value for N that is small enough so the result never overflows.  Encoding this approach in a helper class:

```
public class FastModulo {
    public FastModulo(ulong maxdividend, ulong divisor) {
        div = divisor;
        int dividendbits = 1 + (int)(Math.Log(maxdividend - 1) / Math.Log(2));
        shift = 64 - dividendbits;
        mult = (ulong)Math.Round((double)(1UL << shift) / divisor);
        //TODO: verify that the approximation is accurate enough.
    }
    public ulong Modulo(ulong value) {
        return value - (div * ((value * mult) >> shift));
    }
    int shift;
    ulong mult, div;
}
```

And using it:

```
public ulong RawModulo_5() {
    var fm = new FastModulo(1000, 5);
    ulong r = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        r += fm.Modulo(i);
    }
}
```

Or the less readable:

```
        r += i - (5 * ((i * 3602879701896397UL) >> 54));
```

It is quite a bit faster in 64-bit mode (don't use in 32), I see a rough x3 improvement on my mobile Haswell.  Achieved by replacing the expensive multi-cycle division by 2 multiplies, a shift and a subtraction.  Each only taking 1 cycle.

There is a //TODO, it needs a check to verify that the approximation does not cause errors when the dividend or divisor get too large.  Not 100% sure how to do this correctly, modular math gives me a headache.  But I'm sure most programmers consider this a curiosity instead of practical code :)  If somebody wants to dig in then please edit the code to add the check, otherwise just run the code both ways to verify that the result is the same.

Comment: That's awesome Hans. "I'm sure most programmers consider this a curiosity instead of practical code " Me included, I never even expected to be able to improve this, but you found a way, +1 for that! I'm actually really impressed that the issue is related to such a low-level concept, I wonder if the x64 `DIV` instruction could benefit from early returning in the case that the upper `n` bits are `0`. This seems like a regression, but I digress. I thank you for the wonderful information you have given me, it's truly remarkable. :)

Comment: @EBrown I considered mentioning that in my answer - about the special case with the upper 32 bits 0 - but I have a feeling they don't do that because it would make 64 bit `div` performance even less predictable than it already is. You'd have a lot of questions on here about "when I divide a number bigger than this, my code runs almost four times slower, WTF!" and it wouldn't be good. Really, as Hans mentioned, compilers should be inserting the special case method when divisors are known constants or literals. The C# compiler still has a long way to go in a lot of respects.

Comment: @EBrown Speaking about compiler improvements, notice in the x64 optimized `Mersenne5` method that the compiler is constantly bouncing values between `rsi` and `rax` between each "step" of the shift-and-AND procedure, which is completely unnecessary. That, and better register allocation, is why the "true inline" method I posted is twice as fast as the `Mersenne5`-in-a-loop method - all of those register bounces are gone in that version.

Comment: If small inputs are likely, it actually is worth it for 64-bit code to check for the upper half of an input being zero and using 32-bit operand-size `div` on Intel CPUs.  Clang/LLVM actually does this optimization when tuning for Sandybridge-family.  [Why does Clang do this optimization trick only from Sandy Bridge onward?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54438477)  (`shr reg, 32` sets ZF if the upper half was all zero).  This could backfire given a random mix of small and large inputs that defeat branch-prediction, but if small is very common it's a big win.